# PHP Memory Limit depends upon System's Hard Disk or RAM?

Tags: php, linux

I want to know if PHP's memory limit depends upon the system's hard disk or RAM?

I tried searching on google for this, but didn't get satisfactory answer to this

Comment: Nothing of both, it depends on the settings of you php.ini.

Comment: Sorry if I sounds confusing, but I want to know from where this memory is coming

Comment: Well ... Memory = RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much ram you allow.. This setting is located at php.ini as **memory_limit**

The system is the one who manages how it gets the necessary ram. If there is RAM available or if it needs to access pagefile (swap), etc..

Answer (score 0):

There are some physical limitations (OS Virtual Memory Size) but you are probably only reaching your allocated memory.
I would recommend to use `ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXXXM');` in your code